# Toggle to mute everything on Windows except audio file played

Tags: windows-10, audio, mute

Is there a way to quickly mute everything including notifications, other apps, etc, so I can listen only to meditation audio tracks without being distracted by some random things requesting administrator privileges to install update? Except going to the mixer and muting them one by one, then setting the do not disturb toggle - I don't want all the hassle to set everything back exactly to as it was.

I can use any player, usually it's AIMP or MPC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the free NirSoft utility
[SoundVolumeView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/sound_volume_view.html)
that can save a sound profile into a file, containing the current volume level
and the mute/unmute state of all sound components and for the default sound devices.
You may later load this file to restore exactly all volume levels and settings.

SoundVolumeView also has
[Command-Line Options](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/sound_volume_view.html#command_line),
where you may use the commands `/SaveProfile` and `/LoadProfile`
for saving and reloading sound profiles.

Comment: Some apps are not in the list until they actually output any sound, like BitComet and Telegram. Muting with "/mute AllAppVolume" doesn't work for them. I'm not sure if muting them separately would be effective, though I'll check.